# Create Many Object for Testing Purposes

Tags: java, spring, object, testing, mocking

I would like to know what, for you, is the best way to create a large amount of Objects.

I give you an example.
i want to mock 50 product, product is a class with field STRING name and INTEGER price.

```
 public class StuffTO {

     String category;
     String name;
     String price;
     String qty;
 }
```

I don't need a particular name or price, they can be random.

Now I would like to know which is the best way to create 50 random product writing less code possible..

Comment: A for loop and `Random`.

Comment: If you want "INTEGER price", then change `String price` to `int price` (perhaps a double would work better). Also, `qty` should probably be an int, or a short.

Comment: I wrote a utility for that in Groovy - http://coffeaelectronica.com/blog/2015/property-randomization.html I have not tested it against Java POJOs but maybe it will provide ideas for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Java implementation of [QuickCheck](http://java.net/projects/quickcheck/pages/Home), which has APIs for generating test data.

> Basically QuickCheck is about generators of data. The QuickCheck runner method is just a fancy for loop implementation. QuickCheck can help in scenarios where whole classes of test cases have to be tested and it is not feasible to write tests for all distinct test scenarios.

There's also JFixture which is available on [github](https://github.com/FlexTradeUKLtd/jfixture) and published to [maven central](http://javalibs.com/artifact/com.flextrade.jfixture/jfixture).
This is still under active development, and feature requests are being honoured.

> JFixture is a Java library to assist in the writing of Unit Tests, particularly when following Test Driven Development. It generates types based on the concept of 'constrained non-determinism', which is an implementation of the Generated Value xUnit test pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You may create random objects in a loop (for example 50 in the code )and store them in any collection (for example Arraylist in the code). The code will run for the limit you give and create objects and store them in Arraylist.

```
int i=0;
ArrayList<StuffTO > TestList= new ArrayList<StuffTO >();
while(i<50) {

    TestList.add(new StuffTO ( "aa"+i, "bb"+i, "cc"+i, "dd"+i));

i++;
}
```

Comment: correct. Adding the required constructor, just for a more complete answer, does the trick (even if it's not "random", but I guess it doesn't really matter). I would also use a `for`, but that's a matter of taste :)

Comment: I would like to use some framework, this because i don't want to add any unuseful utility classes to my project.. I try with JFixtture adviced by ekostadinov, and it works fine! And moreover it permit me to define a range of value...

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<StuffTO> create(final int amount){
    final Random random = new Random();
    final List<StuffTO> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<amount;i++){
        list.add(new StuffTO("cat"+random.nextInt(100), "name"+random.nextInt(100), "price"+random.nextInt(100), "qty"+random.nextInt(100)));
    }
    return list;
}

class StuffTO {
    String category;
    String name;
    String price;
    String qty;

    public StuffTO(){

    }
    public StuffTO(String category, String name, String price, String qty) {
        this.category = category;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.qty = qty;
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the default constructor?

Comment: Got used to that, because some packages (gson, jackson) need default constructors to auto map the pojo. To be on the safe side. I don't know what this object has to do further...

Answer (score -1):

```
List<StuffTo> stuff = new ArrayList<>;
List<String> categories = {"category1", "category2", ....};
List<String> names = {"name1", "name2", ....};
List<String> prices = {"price1", "price2", ....};
List<String> qtys= {"qty1", "qty2", ....};

for(int i = 0; i <= 50; i++){
    StuffTo stuffTo = new StuffTo;
    stuffTo.category = catefories[i];
    stuffTo.name = names[i];
    stuffTo.price = prices[i];
    stuffTo.qty = qtys.[i];
    stuff.Add(stuffTo);
}
```

this is just a Basic Idea. Now you just have to iterate thru the stuff list. Hope it helps.

-Fabian

Comment: not a very good approach. the user has to write 200 (or 204...) strings and it is not compiling, also.